# Permissions - how to deny access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've uploaded an image to my s3 bucket.

The image has no permissions on it.

When I view the link to the image in a browser, I can still see the image.

But with no permissions I should be denied access.

Am I missing something?

---

### EDIT

It appears the policy on the entire bucket was superseding individual permissions.

I have now created a new bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "My Policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow All",
            "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Deny Secret",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/secret"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow Secret To Cloudfront",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E2HSIHYIUS8D"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/secret"
    }
]
}
```

This still fails to work. I'm trying to allow access to everything in my bucket, but deny the secret folder to everyone except my cloudfront user.

Where am I going wrong? Are my policies in the wrong order, in which order does Amazon evaluate them?

Comment: I tried to recreate your scenario and could not. I created a new bucket, uploaded an image, and tried to access the link without success. Does your bucket have any permissions attached to it?

Comment: Yes, there are some permissions, I've delved into the policy and created a new one, still am having issues tho. Will update the question.

Comment: Is it resolved ?